# Joomla, add task parameter for specific view

Tags: xml, view, joomla, task

I try to add url parameter task=all vehicles, but after menu link to this view has been created the task parameter still absent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="Multiple Categories">
        <message><![CDATA[Displays a selected categories of an application]]></message>
    </layout>

    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="params" addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_vehiclemanager/elements" label="Params">
            <field name="categorylayout" type="categorylayout" default="1" class="inputbox" label="Select layout" multiple ="false" size="1" description="Choose a layout" required="false" />
            <field name="back_button" type="list" label="Back Button" required="false" description="Show/Hide a Back Button" >
                <option value="">Use Global</option>
                <option value="0">Hide</option>
                <option value="1">Show</option>
            </field>
            <field name="single_category" type="category" default="1" class="inputbox" label="Category" multiple ="true" size="1" description="Choose a vehicle Categories" required="true" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
    <url>
        <param name="task" value="all_vehicles" ></param>
    </url>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this-

```
<!-- Add fields to the request variables for the layout. -->
<fields name="request">
    <fieldset name="request">    
        <field name="task" type="hidden"
            label=""
            required=""
            description=""
            default="all_vehicles"
        />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

Comment: It seems that <fields> have no influence to the query string ?!

Comment: @SergeyOnishchenko: when you'll save the menu it'll append &task=all_vehicles to the link.Is this not you need?

Comment: Is possible add the controller in the task parameter? like ...&task=mycontroller.mycustomtask... ??? I've tried to put in default like default="mycontroller.all_vehicles" but doesn't work, only shows the function instead controller.function
Thanks.

Comment: @BruneX:It should work.It might be cache.First logout then login again and see if it adds task what you have specified in the request variable.

Comment: @Irfan You really understend me? if I put this code ("&task=controller.function") in attr "default" of field "name=task", the JOOMLA traduce this as "&view=controller&task=function" and this really not work for me. Why joomla documentation for 2.5 or higher is so poor or obsolete in many cases? Thans for the reply! :)

Comment: @Irfan: Thanks. Is there any way to not include "view=index" in the link? When I am doing above example, It adds up "index.php?com_mycomponent?view=index". Can I get rid of this ?